# INDEX MATCH 2 columns multiple rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-columns

I've been trying to use the INDEX MATCH formula for the following table, to display the desired value in cell K6. I've been able to get the correct cell to display in K6 as long as K3 = Result1. However, when I try to populate K3 = any other cell between D2:H2, I receive the #REF error in K6. Please help! I'm not sure why it won't populate.

[Snapshot of example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEtKW.jpg)

Comment: How about updating your formula to the question?

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=INDEX(C:H,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$3:$A$14)/(($A$3:$A$14=K3)*($B$3:$B$14=K4)),1),MATCH(K5,$C$2:$H$2,0))
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @Brittany please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.